# (Android-Eclipse)Duplicate method onClick(View) error in .java archive while inserting a 3rd button

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick, duplicates, onclicklistener

I had two buttons working great when I tried to import a third one into my archive AboutScreen.java which is related to a .xml file located to the android/layout.

When I inserted the third one the error message was : "Duplicate method onClick(View) in type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

My third button's id is : button_contact_info.Do you have any idea why I have this error?

```
    mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    button_contact_info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_contact_info);

    mStartButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myintent2 = new Intent(AboutScreen.this,
                    Museum_info.class);
            startActivity(myintent2);

        }

    });

    // Intent gia to Museum_Contact_Info.class

    button_contact_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myintent3 = new Intent(AboutScreen.this,
                    Museum_Contact_Info.class);
            startActivity(myintent3);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem you have in your code. Just try to clean your project and run it again. Might be the button's id that you are generating is not updated in **R.java** file that's why you are getting error.

Still if you face any error then please post your log-cat as well as whole code in question.